# Bootstrap Carousel giving Invalid Selection Error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 3.3 carousel on my web page and I load a list of pics that rotate. The carousel works fine but if the user clicks on either the right or left arrow to advance the pic manually a javascript error dialog pops up and says it is an invalid selection. I have triple checked that the bootstrap js file is loading correctly and it would seem that since the carousel works properly on automatic mode that the css files are correct. Can someone tell me where to look to fix this Invalid Selection error? I have searched the bootstrap.js file and it does not have this specific message so it is coming from somewhere else. The code connected to the left and right arrow is as simple anchor tag with href="#introCarousel"  role="button" data-slide="prev"

Comment: it will be easier to help you if you add some of your code.

Comment: Post your code to a Fiddle please.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time. The issue was an extension in Chrome causing problems. Once the extension was disabled it worked. Thanks,
Terry